# python pip: cannot install flask and zappa - contradicting requirements

Tags: python, flask, pipenv

I want to install flask and zappa, a common combination.

I use pipenv to create an evironment:

> pipenv --python 3.6.4

I want to install packages:

> pipenv install flask zappa

Unfortunately the requirements of flask is:

> Werkzeug >= 0.14

the requirement of zappa is :

> Werkzeug == 0.12

So this is not installable. What can i do?

Comment: No idea but I'm surprised that Python can't just keep different versions of the dependency for the respective libraries.

Comment: on github zappa has updated requirements to Werkzeug==0.14. pip repo seems to lag behind. Can I install with pipenv from github somehow?

Comment: @caliph: you can specify a git address in pipfile: https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/blob/master/examples/Pipfile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Evgeny this solution was successful. I could not find it in pipenv documentation.

Just manually edit the Pipfile:

```
Pipfile
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[dev-packages]



[packages]

zappa = { git = 'https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa.git', ref = 'master', editable = true }
flask = "*"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```